# Data unavailable to Collaborators on google collab using google.colab import files

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

We are 4 people working on the google Colaboratory's Ipyothon Notebook. I was able to upload file for myself. But it was not available to the other users. It generates an error message for them. It recognizes the file uploaded by me. Would be great if someone could help in tackling this in a neat way. Seems like a very basic functionality of Colaboratory.

```
 enter code here`from google.colab import files
 uploaded = files.upload()


 ## Checks the files uploaded 
 for fn in uploaded.keys():
 print('User uploaded file "{name}" with length {length} bytes'.format(name=fn, 
 length=len(uploaded[fn])))


 import pandas as pd
 my_file = pd.read_csv("data_assignment1.csv")
 print(my_file.head())
```

Gives the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-06e7ca74a847> in <module>()
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 my_file = pd.read_csv("data_assignment1.csv")
      3 print(my_file.head())

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    707                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    708 
--> 709         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    710 
    711     parser_f.__name__ = name

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    447 
    448     # Create the parser.
--> 449     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    450 
    451     if chunksize or iterator:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    816             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
    817 
--> 818         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    819 
    820     def close(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1047     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
   1048         if engine == 'c':
-> 1049             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1050         else:
   1051             if engine == 'python':

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1693         kwds['allow_leading_cols'] = self.index_col is not False
   1694 
-> 1695         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1696 
   1697         # XXX

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: File b'data_assignment1.csv' does not exist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that, although the notebook is shared between collaborators, the machine instance is created for each of them. So, when you upload the data, your collaborators won’t see it because it’s on different machine. So you can either

- let them upload it again for each of them, from their local machine.
- change to load data through `wget` or `git` or Google Drive where each of them will repeat the downloading. Still, they won’t need to have data uploaded through their local machine.